# css show full image on click div?

Tags: css

If I have an image bigger than 200px height I will crop this image with a div:

```
.voltaimgdiv{
 max-height:200px;
 display:block;  
 line-height:200px;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="voltaimgdiv">
<img src="http://www.pineswcd.com/vertical/Sites/%7BB4CF315C-B365-47D6-A226-5F80C04C0D48%7D/uploads/tree_clipart.gif">
</div>
```

my problem is, I want this div to grow and show full image if user clicks on it.
Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/64f36m4y/

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend by using toggleClass.

Better set the height and width of the div and image auto. After using on click function.

JS

```
jQuery(function($){
             $('.voltaimgdiv').click(function(){
             $('.voltaimgdiv').toggleClass('full')
             })
        })
```

CSS

```
.full img{
  width:100%;
}

.full{
  max-height:100% !important;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/4k267qLa/)

Comment: Don't mention it my friend @RickJoe . If there anything you need help, you can contact me ! :D

Answer (score 2):

you can maximize image height on click using this css code

```
.voltaimgdiv:active{
  max-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: This answer hmm ok ok. better set the height auto.

Comment: But you know you used max-height and max-height can't be auto

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do with CSS.Just Assign ID And Use it in CSS.

**HTML:**

`<div id="clkme" class="voltaimgdiv">
<img src="http://www.pineswcd.com/vertical/Sites/%7BB4CF315C-B365-47D6-A226-5F80C04C0D48%7D/uploads/tree_clipart.gif">
</div>`

**CSS:**

```
#clkme:active{
  max-height:500px;
  }
```

You can Write Javascript As Well And Javascript is a better choice.
by using

> Onclick="Name"

Function In div.
and make a body of javascript

```
function Name{
\\your code ..
}
```

Comment: ID on css called using "#" not "."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('.voltaimgdiv').click(function() {
    $('.voltaimgdiv').css('height', 'auto');
});
```

```css
.voltaimgdiv {
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="voltaimgdiv">
    <img src="http://www.pineswcd.com/vertical/Sites/%7BB4CF315C-B365-47D6-A226-5F80C04C0D48%7D/uploads/tree_clipart.gif">
</div>

show all image on click?
```

Comment: Please don't circumvent the rules requiring you to post your code **in the post itself**. Linking to JSFiddle is only OK if you've included real code.